# Serial Port not working after disabling login shell

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm trying to write a small program in node.js to communicate over serial port. I'm using node.js for that with a sample code like that:

```
var SerialPort = require("serialport");
var serialPort = new SerialPort("/dev/ttyAMA0", {
  baudrate: 9600
});

serialPort.on("open", function () {
  console.log('open');

  serialPort.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('data received: ' + data);
  });

  setInterval(function () {
    serialPort.write(new Buffer('4', 'ascii'), function (err, results) {
      console.log('err ' + err);
      console.log('results ' + results);
    });
  }, 1000);
});
```

This is however not working at all after i disable the login shell over serial port serial port in raspi-config. After that i'm unable to send/recieve any data.

I connected pin 8 with pin 10 to create a self-loop and tried using minicom to send something over it with no success as well.
I checked the /boot/config.txt and enable_uart is set to 1.
I also checked the /boot/cmdline.txt and there are no entries with AMA0 port.

Can anybody provide me with a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking for solution - this did it for me and opened a serial port.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=159984&p=1039065#p1039065